# How to get total packet length in heuristic registered function?

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

How can i get the total packet length in heuristic register function is_ixia_trailer

```
ixia_trailer_proto:register_heuristic("eth.trailer", is_ixia_trailer)
```

With buffer:len() i get length of the trailer but not the full message length

```
local function is_ixia_trailer(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    local length = buffer:len()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are interested in the frame length and/or frame captured length?

```
local f_frame_len = Field.new("frame.len")
local f_frame_cap_len = Field.new("frame.cap_len")
```

A simple example of using those fields:

```
pinfo.cols.info:append("Frame Len: " .. f_frame_len().value .. " bytes, Cap Len: " .. f_frame_cap_len().value .. " bytes")
```